# Substring with two possibilities regex

Tags: python, regex

I extracted 1 long string from a webpage. Using:

```
 x=re.findall(r"(?:l'article)\s\d+\w+.*;", xpath)
```

It extracted the following 2 strings:

```
 l'article 1382 du code civil ;
 l'article 700 du code de procédure civile, les condamne à payer à la société Financière du cèdre la somme globale de 3 000 euros et rejette leurs demandes ;
```

However, the latter one is a bit long. All I need is up to the ','. is there a way to do this directly ? So have my original regex command look for either the ';' or the ',' based on which one it encounters first.

If not, can I apply regex to a list, or do I need to write a loop for that ?

Required outcome a list with:

```
 l'article 1382 du code civil
 l'article 700 du code de procédure civile
```

Note, I have to apply this to many pages and there might be many more of these in a page. Doing anything by hand or by specifically indicating an entry in a list is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things you seem to be missing the ungreedy operator, `?` in order to force the regex to stop searching after it find the first occurrence. Additionally, you can check for multiple characters by using `[]` (refer to the following).  Here would be the new code:

```
(?:l'article)\s\d+\w+.*?[;,]
```

Regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/tYkNHK/1

Comment: Why not `[;,]`? And with `re.findall` your code will return only `;` or `,` as you are creating a capturing group.

Comment: @SebastianProske Updated the code, thanks for the input.

Comment: Thank you. I originally thought it would be the ?(;|,) answer you provided before. But this supplied a list of ; and ,. (Sorry for not providing my own attempt at solving this question in the set up). Thanks for explaining why this happened @SebastianProske .

Comment: Yes, you finished it before the minimum time to accept a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your regex a lot:

- `(?:l'article)` -> there is no need for the non-capturing group, so you could just remove it
- `\s\d+\w+` -> the check for `\w+` seems rather pointless (especially as this matches numbers without letters), so I think you could remove it. Or you are missing a space character to match e.g. `1382 du`
- `.*;` to match anything up to `,` or `;` you can simply use a negated character class, like `[^;,]*` which will match everything that's not one of those.

So your final regex could be either

```
l'article\s\d+[^;,]*
```

or

```
l'article\s\d+\s\w+[^;,]*
```